# Security issues with v7.59

Tags: security

I have updated various Drupal 7 sites to version 7.59 (and included all relevant updates) because of the security update.  However I've still experienced issues with sites being hacked, there were also no warnings or issues reported on the site report when the update was completed.  Yesterday an attack lead to malicious phishing code being inserted into a website, Google has now flagged this site.  The malicious code has now been removed.

Are there any other known security vulnerabilities or patches that are available for Drupal 7?

Comment: No good way to answer this without full access to the entire application.

Comment: Probably your site was hacked before you done the updates. When did you update your sites? Immediately after they were published? If not, according to Drupal.org, "[s]ites not patched by Wednesday, 2018-04-11 may be compromised. This is the date when evidence emerged of automated attack attempts. It is possible targeted attacks occurred before that." FAQ: https://groups.drupal.org/security/faq-2018-002 If your site got hacked: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/security/your-drupal-site-got-hacked-now-what

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Yes the site was hacked before the updates were done.  The clean site went back up though.  Could there be a further vulnerability?

Comment: If the site was hacked before, my advice is that you install your backups to a new server. The once hacked server is contaminated and you cannot be sure that the attacker has installed any backdoors. You should also make sure that your backups are clean. Please read this page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/security/your-drupal-site-got-hacked-now-what

Answer (score 3):

Most likely there are still hacked/inserted files in your code base thats leaving an opening for the attacker to rexploit. After updating to 7.59 you need to go through the files/code and remove anything that's not supposed to be there. Very hard if you're not using git. Also also includes the /sites/default/files folder and subfolders as well as all other directories